# Input Multiple Var to Function, Search JSON Array, and Receive Multiple Array Val as Output

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, for-loop

I have a json array, in a javascript function. The function takes input, searches the array for key/val, and gives me the value I need.

What I am trying to accomplish is input a string of variables like:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Into this function:

```
function getF(fid) {
var flist = [
{
"fintid":1,
"featureint":"See Remarks"
},
{
"fintid":2,
"featureint":"Accessory Apt"
},
{
"fintid":3,
"featureint":"Alarm: Fire"
},
{
"fintid":4,
"featureint":"Alarm: Security"
},
{
"fintid":5,
"featureint":"Bar: Dry"
}
]
for(var i = 0; i < flist.length; i++)
{
    if(flist[i].fintid == fid) {
        return flist[i].featureint;
    }
}
}
```

And receive all corresponding "featureint" values, that match with all fid/fintid given to the function. I can do this if I give only one number. I want to give multiple numbers, and receive multiple values... Please help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the past in value is an array (not a string delimited by `,` - if it is, split it to get an array) - you can use `indexOf` to check the looped over object ID against the array. Push all matches to an array, then return:

```
function getF(fid) {
    //Split and cast to array of numbers
    fid = fid.split(",").map(function(i) { return parseInt(i) });

    var flist = [
        {
            "fintid":1,
            "featureint":"See Remarks"
        },
        {
            "fintid":2,
            "featureint":"Accessory Apt"
        }
        ..
    ]

    var matches = [];       

    for(var i = 0; i < flist.length; i++) {
        if(fid.indexOf(flist[i].fintid) > -1) {
            matches.push(flist[i].featureint);
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
getF("1,2");
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5p4wmjyu/

Comment: I tried this code, but the output comes out blank. Yes, the fid input, is literally a string of numbers delimited by a comma, which I have tried splitting.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the arguments into an array, then use indexOf as others have suggested. Note the result in this case is an array of featureint values, as that's what I understand you're after.

```js
function getF(fid) {
var flist = [
{
"fintid":1,
"featureint":"See Remarks"
},
{
"fintid":2,
"featureint":"Accessory Apt"
},
{
"fintid":3,
"featureint":"Alarm: Fire"
},
{
"fintid":4,
"featureint":"Alarm: Security"
},
{
"fintid":5,
"featureint":"Bar: Dry"
}
];

var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

return flist.reduce(function(matches, current) {
if(args.indexOf(current.fintid) > -1) {
   matches.push(current.featureint);
} 
 return matches;
}, []);
}

var result = getF(1, 3, 4);
console.log(result);

var stringArg = "1, 2, 5";
//apply to pass an array in as args, split to make the array from the string, then map to convert from string to number
result = getF.apply(this, stringArg.split(',').map(function(x){ return Number(x.trim())}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This one looks like it will probably work pretty nicely. One moment while I try it out

Comment: If you want the whole objects instead of the featureint vals, it would just be a matter of changing the matches.push(current.featureint) to matches.push(current)

Comment: Odd. It works exactly as it should here. In my code, the getF(1, 2, 3); is a variable/string of numbers like fid = 1,2,3 ... yet in my code, it returns blank...?

Comment: A single variable containing a string = "1, 2, 3" or similar?

Comment: Yes, literally, if I do a console.log, the output shows as 1,2,3, no quotes, or  spaces

Comment: Please do a console.log(typeof(fid));  I want to be certain I understand what you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98612/discussion-between-mic-and-user3259138).

Answer (score 0):

As a variant, if you don't know how many parameters you have, you can use ***apply*** function

```js
function getF() {
  var flist = [{
    "fintid": 1,
    "featureint": "See Remarks"
  }, {
    "fintid": 2,
    "featureint": "Accessory Apt"
  }, {
    "fintid": 3,
    "featureint": "Alarm: Fire"
  }, {
    "fintid": 4,
    "featureint": "Alarm: Security"
  }, {
    "fintid": 5,
    "featureint": "Bar: Dry"
  }];
  var newArray = [];
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);

  for (var i = 0; i < flist.length; i++) {
    if (args.indexOf(flist[i].fintid) > -1) {
      newArray.push(flist[i].featureint);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

console.log(getF.apply(null, [2, 5]));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to accomplish this

```js
var flist = [
{
"fintid":1,
"featureint":"See Remarks"
},
{
"fintid":2,
"featureint":"Accessory Apt"
},
{
"fintid":3,
"featureint":"Alarm: Fire"
},
{
"fintid":4,
"featureint":"Alarm: Security"
},
{
"fintid":5,
"featureint":"Bar: Dry"
}
]

var searchInt = 3;

alert(flist.filter(function(v){
if(v['fintid']===searchInt){
return true;
}
return false;
},searchInt)[0]['featureint']);

//FOR ARRAY INPUT

var input = [1,2,3];
alert(input.map(function(val){
return flist.filter(function(v){
if(v['fintid']===val){
return true;
}
return false;
},val)[0]['featureint'];
}).toString());
```

Comment: What if I want to searchInt = 3,4,5 ??

Comment: @user3259138 you can use array map in conjunction to return multiple values. see updated example.